# Processing xml in Linq (C#) : Count descendents / elements and Check count = X

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, hyperlink, count

Given the XML document:

```
<Root xmlns="http://foo" xmlns:bar="http://bar">
    <Child Name="one" bar:Type="type1" />
    <Child Name="two" bar:Caption="captionvalue" /> 
</Root>
```

What is the most efficient way to do the following using the XElement root (that has the element Root):

1. Make sure there are only two Child elements as descendents
2. For each attribute in each Child element, if namespace is http://bar then call BarFunction(attribute.value) else call NoBarFunction(attribute.value)
3. If I need to process each attribute of Child differently based on their Name (eg: populate a set of variables with the values) is the only option an if-else on Attribute.Name inside the foreach (Attribute) block ?

Am I correct in assuming that attribute that do not have the "http://bar" namespace are actually in some default namespace (and not in http://foo) unlike the elements who inherit the namespace of the parent if not qualified?

I have:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> children = root.Elements("Child");
// How do I test the count? And get each Child
foreach (XAttribute attribute in child.Attributes())
{
   if (attribute.Name.Namespace.ToString() == "http://bar")
   {
BarFunction(attribute.Value);
   }
   else //Default Namespace
   {
      NoBarFunction(attribute.Value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Attributes which have no namespace prefix are deemed not to belong to any namespace. I think of it as "the global unnamed namespace" if that helps. So you are right. The Name attribute in `<Child Name="one" bar:Type="type1" />` is NOT in the root namespace of `http://foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ would be the most efficient way. Something like (from memory):

```
IEnumerable<XElement> results = root.Elements("child").Where(el => el.Children.Count == 2)
```

And then performing your check on your `results` to see what the namespace is and then performing the method on that/those XElement(s). This could also be done in LINQ using similar syntax to above.

For point 3, you could use a `switch` block which would probably be more appropriate, though it is up to you to decide on the architecture. E.g. if the elements are a set of predefined values, then you could also use LINQ to populate your variables.

Comment: When you use e1.Children.count Wouldnt that check if each "Child" node has exactly two children?

Answer (score 0):

API: **[Extensions.GetSchemaInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342577.aspx)**

Thinking out of the box, you want to know which schema an attribute (or element or...) was declared in.

In the 'XML reading' role, that would be which schema *validated* that node.

In validating parser jargon this information is part of the PVSI (*Post Validation Schema Infoset*).  You can get to that information by calling, e.g.

```
public static void Validate(
    this XDocument source,
    XmlSchemaSet schemas,
    ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler,
    bool addSchemaInfo
)
```

**[With `addSchemaInfo` set to true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354954.aspx)**.

If addSchemaInfo is true, this method populates the XML tree with the post-schema-validation infoset (PSVI).

There are two steps to populating the XML tree with the PSVI.

1. First, an annotation is added to all nodes in the tree to enable you to call Extensions.GetSchemaInfo or Extensions.GetSchemaInfo on an element or attribute in the tree.
2. Second, default elements and attributes defined in the XSD are added to the XML tree. By calling one of the GetSchemaInfo methods, you can determine if a specific element or attribute was added from the XSD as a default element or attribute.